# unable to add counter in Flink 1.3.2

Tags: counter, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am trying to add a counter in Flink as mentioned [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter), but the issue is that counter.inc() is returning void instead of Integer. Code for my Metric is given as below

```java
    private  static class myMetric extends RichMapFunction<String,Integer> {
       private Counter counter ;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            super.open(parameters);
            this.getRuntimeContext().
                    getMetricGroup().
                    counter("countit");
        }

        @Override
        public Integer map(String s) throws Exception {

            return this.counter.inc();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work better if you assign a value to your counter:

```java
    this.counter = getRuntimeContext()
      .getMetricGroup()
      .counter("countit");
```

You may find [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#counter) helpful.